# Why doesn't Google calculate data quantity conversions using binary, and instead just moves the decimal point left/right?

Tags: binary, decimal, bing

[image: Why, Google?]

I already understand the fundamentals behind why the two calculations are different. I just want to know how can I get Google to give me the same binary conversion result that Bing does, because I don't feel like using Bing just to convert data quantities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MiB and KiB when you want the 1024 version as from the [Kilobyte wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilobyte): "In the International System of Quantities, the kilobyte (symbol kB) is 1000 bytes, while the kibibyte (symbol KiB) is 1024 bytes.

[1 MiB to KiB](https://www.google.com/search?q=1%20MiB%20to%20KiB)